# Hook archive-product.php woocommerce (Overriding Issues)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried all the solutions posted to StackOverflow and still no dice.

Woocommerce mentions that "archive-product" will not be able to be overwritten if you use woocommerce.php, so what is the correct way to loop  woocommerce_content(); ? and still be able to edit archive-product? No matter what I do, I can't edit archive-product. I did have success with this, but this seems like bad practice;

```
if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
    woocommerce_content();
} else {
    //For ANY product archive.
    //Product taxonomy, product search or /shop landing
    woocommerce_get_template( 'archive-product.php' );
}
```

Another solution most people find in function.php (which I already use)

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}

add_theme_support('woocommerce');
```

I haven't seen anyone asking about this in my hours of research and would love some help.

This is very vague and basically just tells you that you can't edit the archive-product (without any solution of how to do so)
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Can this help you? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-theme-developer-handbook/

Comment: @VincenzoDiGaetano Yes and no. That's exactly what I followed, but it doesn't tell you how to hook the archive-product or what you should do in order to style that page